# Ruby on Rails with React Display link_to

Tags: reactjs

I'm using Ruby on Rails with React.
I wanna display ruby_root_path in My link

```
class Navbar extends Component{
render(){
    return (
        <nav>
            <div className="container nav-wrapper">
              <a href="#" className="brand-logo">Brand</a>
              <ul id="nav-mobile" className="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                <li><a href="">Accueil</a></li>
                <li><a href="<%= link_to about_path %>">About us</a></li>
                <li><a href="/offers">Offers</a></li>
                <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="/signup">Signup</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    )
}}
```

Comment: You have made a statement here, and posted some code, but haven't actually asked a question.

Comment: Also, I think the code you are trying to write is discussed here:  Possible duplicate of [React JSX integration with erb and Ruby block syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35133698/react-jsx-integration-with-erb-and-ruby-block-syntax)

Comment: User js-routes,  check https://github.com/railsware/js-routes and https://github.com/railsware/js-routes/issues/237